# Cannot get the average date using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series data set from which I want to get an average date. Here is a contrived example that shows an overflow error of pandas datetime64 object:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = pd.date_range('2000/1/1', periods=500, freq='D')
s = pd.Series(rng)
minT = s.min()
np.mean(s - minT)
```

The output is:

```
Out[9]:

Timedelta('-178 days +11:48:31.852580')
```

Is there any way around this problem? Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue, see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6549). It is a straightforward fix and on the list. As a work-around, cast to milliseconds, mean, and back.

```
In [14]: pd.to_timedelta((s-s.min()).astype('m8[ms]').mean(),unit='ms')
Out[14]: Timedelta('249 days 12:00:00')
```

Comment: Could you tell me where I can find the doc for the 'm8[ms]' type you used here?

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html it is timedelta64[ms]