# Average time between transactions or orders BY users in panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have about 2 million rows...I've found a bunch of answers that get the average time in totality - but I'm trying to get the average time each timestamp, per user. Also not banned status must = 1.

```
 UID timestamp             Not_banned
 3   2013-05-02 08:42:44   1
 2   2013-05-02 14:05:57   1
 2   2013-05-02 17:36:51   1
```

So the output would something like

```
 UID avg_btwn_txn
 3   1.5
 2   63.2
 6   22.1
```

I tried:

df.groupby("UID")["timestamp"].mean()

...but this code just errors out.

"DataError: No numeric types to aggregate"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need first [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filtering and then `groupby` with custom lambda function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31929638/2901002) (`timedeltas` are converted to `hours` and back convert to `timedelatas` was removed):

```
df1 = df[df['Not_banned'] == 1]
         .groupby('UID')
         .Timestamp
         .apply(lambda x: (x-x.min()).astype('m8[h]').mean())
         .reset_index()

print (df1)
   UID  Timestamp
0    2        1.5
1    3        0.0
```

Another solution with [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df1 = df.query("Not_banned == 1")
        .groupby('UID').Timestamp
        .apply(lambda x: (x-x.min()).astype('m8[h]').mean())
        .reset_index()
```

Comment: Can you help me understand what x-x.min() is doing there?

Comment: Yes, it substract all values with minimal value, so output is series of timedeltas. Then are converted to `hours` where is possible find `mean`